# group_by one column but keeping multiples based off another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with thousands of rows looking like this:

```
    time  Unique_ID  Unix_Time Event          Version
    <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>    <lgl>          <dbl>
 1  1404 4961657804 1565546745 FALSE              6
 2  2534 4453645779 1550934792 FALSE              5
 3  2114 3602935494 1512593418 TRUE               3
 4  2605 5343699852 1586419012 TRUE               6
 5  1246 5095942046 1572689498 FALSE              6
 6  2519 3206995213 1495881898 TRUE               3
 7  1419 4958551504 1565434177 TRUE               6
 8  2262 5441937631 1590754817 TRUE               6
 9  1650 3024892331 1488210079 TRUE               2
10  1880 3163703804 1494173662 FALSE              2
```

I manipulate the data frame using the following command:

```
df <- df %>%
   group_by(minute = findInterval(time, seq(min(0), max(9000), 60))) %>%
   summarise(Number= n(), 
             Won = sum(Event))
```

Now my data frame looks like this:

```
    minute  Number     Won
    <int>  <int>      <int>
 1     55    264        128
 2     71     34         17
 3     31   1427        728
 4     80      9          5
 5     24   1197        673
 6    141      1          1
 7     53    326        163
 8     30   1572        802
 9     77     14          9
10     97      1          1
```

I would want something like this though:

```
    minute  Number     Won     Version
    <int>  <int>      <int>    <int>
 1     55    264        128      1
 2     55     34         17      2
 3     55   1427        728      3
 4     80      9          5      1
 5     24   1197        673      1
 6    141      1          1      2
 7     53    326        163      3
 8     53   1572        802      4
 9     77     14          9      2
10     97      1          1      6
```

Is it possible to keep the rows with different `Versions` seperated while grouping `time`?

Comment: It was meant as an example to show that a minute should be able to have multiple entries based on the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can group by 2 columns: minute and Version

```
df <- df %>%
   group_by(minute = findInterval(time, seq(min(0), max(9000), 60)), Version)
```